# Why is there a possible loss of precision converting a String to double?

Tags: java, string, double

```
for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  line = file.readLine();
  String[] word = line.split(";");

  appartment[i] = new Appartment();
  appartment[i].floor= Integer.parseInt(word[0]);
  appartment[i].name = word[1];
  appartment[i].money= Double.parseDouble(word[2]);
  appartment[i].owner= word[3];
}
```

Could someone tell my why this is not working? Im reading from a file. I am trying to convert money from string to double, but it says

```
possible loss of precision. 
required: int
found: double
```

I need doubles so the owners account also can go negative.

Comment: *"need double so the owners account also can go negative"* An `int` can be negative.  Note that monetary values should normally be expressed as int values (in cents) too avoid the horrors of floating point representations of numbers.

Comment: Not to mention that floating point types should not be used for storing financial values such as money...

Comment: Not to mention that Apartment is spelled incorrectly.

Comment: I also removed the `homework` tag, as this is now depricated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**-** It seems that `appartment` is an Array of type `Appartment`, where the Appartement's object field named `money` is in `int` type.

**-** But you are assingnig it the value as `double` type, so you will need an **explicit cast** from double to int,

**Eg:**

`appartment[i].money= (int) Double.parseDouble(word[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `appartment[i].money= Double.parseDouble(word[2]);` is a problem here. If the type of money is `int`, either you should cast the value of word[2] to `int` like 
`appartment[i].money = (int(Double.parseDouble(word[2]));` 
or you should parse as an integer something like 
 `appartment[i].money= Integer.parseInt(word[2]);`

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
  appartment[i].money = Integer.parseInt(word[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have in defenition of appartment that money is int, try to change it to double...

Answer (score 0):

The best practice when representing money in Java is to use BigDecimal. See: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13 for more details.